# Can't see Indigo or Helios from Eclipse Check for Updates

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm currently running Eclipse 3.52, 'Galileo', on Ubuntu.   I need to upgrade my version of the ADT, which requires a newer version of Eclipse.

Under Window>Preferences>Install/Update>Available software sites I only have 3 sites, the ADT at http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ (Disabled) and the Helios and Indigo sites at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios and    http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo, respectively,  both **En**abled.

I also have "Show all versions of available software" checked and "When software selected for Install Wizard may not be compatible, open the wizaed anyway" set.  But when I run Help>**check for updates,** I can see it searching the Indigo and Helios sites, but when it finishes it only shows me "Subversion SVN Team Provider".    Why isn't it showing me Indigo or Helios updates, and why IS it showing me Subversion?

And yes I did stop and restart Eclipse many times.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have been trying this all evening without any success :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you have to go and download Helios or Indigo and install it, I don't think it will jump up to the newer versions.  Checking updates will just get you the latest version of Galileo.

Comment: Hmm, well in any case, I successfully upgraded to Indigo from Galileo by simply downloading it and installing it!